# Based on the unique values of one column sum other Column in SQL

Tags: hive, hbase, hiveql

I have below SQL table with name TEST_T

```
SKU_ID      DC_ID         CRT_DTTM                  FIELD_NAME    TOTAL 
------------------------------------------------------------------------
sku1        dc1     2017-08-02 02:28:41.711         FIELD1        5
sku1        dc1     2017-08-01 01:28:41.711         FIELD1        4             
sku2        dc1     2017-08-02 03:12:10.064         FIELD1        6
sku2        dc1     2017-08-01 04:12:10.064         FIELD1        1        
sku3        dc2     2017-08-02 07:32:46.795         FIELD1        3            
sku4        dc2     2017-08-02 10:44:09.347         FIELD1        2
```

And there are lot of records with different DC_ID's, the above are just for instance.
And I have a below working query which will sum the TOTAL for all the records which have DC_ID as dc1

```
select A.DC_ID , sum(TO_NUMBER(A.TOTAL)) as SUM FROM (
Select A.DC_ID, A.SKU_ID, A.CRT_DTTM, A.FIELD_NAME, A.TOTAL
FROM TEST_T A
INNER JOIN (
Select DC_ID, FIELD_NAME, Max(CRT_DTTM) as LatestDate, SKU_ID  from TEST_T
Where DC_ID = 'dc1'
AND FIELD_NAME = 'FIELD1'
Group By DC_ID, FIELD_NAME, SKU_ID
) B
on A.CRT_DTTM = B.LatestDate 
and A.SKU_ID = B.SKU_ID
and A.DC_ID = B.DC_ID
and A.FIELD_NAME = B.FIELD_NAME)
Group By A.DC_ID;
```

which will give the result as

```
A.DC_ID     SUM 
---------------
dc1         11
```

How to modify the above query in a generic way to handle lot many DC_ID's such a way that I will get the result as below

```
A.DC_ID     SUM 
---------------
dc1         11
dc2         5
dc3         7
dc4         9
dc5         18
etc.....
```

Comment: change your `where` condition in the subquery: `Where DC_ID = 'dc1'
AND FIELD_NAME = 'FIELD1'` is what is preventing other `dc_id`.

Comment: I believe it's because you are joining on the latest date of `dc1` which is `2017-08-02 03:12:10.064`. Cast the dates as `Date` to get what you want.

Comment: You've tagged this question sql-server, but Microsoft's sql server does not support `to_number`. Which RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Actually I'm using Hbase and using SquirrelSQL to run the query

Comment: I changed the condition to Where DC_ID in (select distinct(DC_ID) from TEST_T) still not working

Answer (score 4):

your output can simply achieve by following query. You haven't explained why you created inner subquery and join. If you explain that query may be different

```
select dc_id, sum(Total) as_sum  from test_t Group by DC_ID
```

You may also try the following query. I haven't tested the result but it give you idea about use of [rank](https://blog.sqlauthority.com/2011/08/12/sql-server-tips-from-the-sql-joes-2-pros-development-series-ranking-functions-rank-dense_rank-and-row_number-day-12-of-35/)

```
    select dc_id,sum(_sum) _sum from
    (
    select sum(total) over partition by(Dc_ID) as _sum,
    rank() over partition by(Dc_ID,skuid order by CRT_DTTM desc) as rno,
    dc_ID
    ) t
    where rno=1
Group by DC_ID
```

Earlier question was tag with `sql-server` so the answer was according to that no it may help someone else working with sql server

Comment: I need the inner query to get the latest record for the particular dc_id

Comment: why you need that latest record as you are not using any thing for that in you desired output. Do you want sum on dc_id along with some column of the latest record of test_t table?

Comment: I need to calculate the sum of TOTAL column for all the latest records of skuIds for the particular dc_id

Comment: What do you mean by latest your first output is 11 while latest of dc1 is sku2 only as per you input

Comment: I Just changed the table data which I provided earlier

Comment: i don't think he can use RANK() in hbase... that link takes him to the code related to Microsoft server

Comment: Now sql-server tag is removed earlier it was there so gave the answer accordingly

Answer (score 0):

why did you use complex query you need a simple query such as below code

```
select DC_ID , sum(TOTAL) as [SUM] FROM TEST_T group by DC_ID
```

now if you need a where for some field you can use code below

```
select DC_ID , sum(TOTAL) as [SUM] FROM TEST_T where FIELD_NAME = 'FIELD1' group by DC_ID
```

if you need more help please let me know...